# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation when looping through object

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to make a for loop which loops a object and should have logged the appropriate value of the instrument respectively, 
but I am getting this unknown error when executing this :

```
gge = true;
for (var ins in instruments) {
    if (gge) {
        this_ = ins;
        console.log(instruments[this_]);
    }
};
```

executing this script is resulting in this error..

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

the instruments object is http://pastebin.com/tRzvpwgU

can anyone please help with solving this?? or explaining why this is happening?

Comment: I am using Chrome Canary build, so is this supposed to be a bug in canary?

Comment: No error in Chrome. I don't see any possible errors. I doubt Chrome Canary build has something to do with it?

Comment: You sure that the block you posted is where the error occurs? On what line?

Comment: Yeah, this is line. console.log(instruments[this_]);

Comment: it says, (anonymous function) @ VM7332:18 in the dropdown of the details of the error in dev tools..

Answer (score 1):

I tried..

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(instruments[meow]));
```

stringing it somehow removes the error.

Comment: Must be bugged, otherwise it makes literally no sense that the console.log does not accept an object.

Comment: Yeah, oh well.. this was just for debugging purposes, but my main function works fine without the console.log debug message.